# Automatically embed twitter link in vBulletin

Tags: javascript, php, twitter, embed, vbulletin

Okay hi there! I currently have a script on my vBulletin forum that one of my friends made who is unfortunately unavailable to help me out. I know this is pretty straight forward and I have been fiddling with it all day to get it to work with not very much success. See below.

```
$embed_player =  '
 <table widht="300" align="center" class="tborder" >
 <tr><td class="alt1">
 <iframe src="http://instagram.com/p/\\4/embed/" frameborder="0" width="280" height="330" scrolling="no"></iframe>
  </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  ';

  $post['message'] = preg_replace('#(<a href="http://instagram.com)?/(embed/([-|~_0-9A-Za-z]+)|p\/([-|~_0-9A-Za-z]+)&?.*?)">(http://instagram.com)?/(embed/([-|~_0-9A-Za-z]+)|p\/([-|~_0-9A-Za-z]+)&?.*?)<\/a>#i', $embed_player, $post['message']);
```

The script above works on the basis, when a user posts a link directly to an instagram video it will automatically embed the link into their post on my vBulletin.

What I am trying to do is when a user posts a full tweet URL (ie https://twitter.com/greigeh/status/590850852161740801 - the number being the "TWEETID") it will automatically embed this. The embedding code for a tweet is on my forum is:

```
<div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadx(data) {
  document.write(data.html);
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/oembed.json?id=TWEETID&callback=loadx"></script>
<div class="twitter" onLoad="loadx().html"/>
</div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

So ultimately I tried putting this code into the script above except I'm having trouble getting the preg_replace to work. I need it to pretty much ignore the whole URL except the TWEETID but i've came to no avail.

Is this an easy change or am I missing something here?

Comment: The Twitter v1 API doesn't work anymore, you'll need to look at v1.1 https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-tweets